# Android - programmatically add TableRows with vertical aligned items

Tags: android, alignment, orientation, tablelayout, tablerow

I am filling in rows in a TableLayout programmatically. Each row contains 3 TextViews, but they are aligned horizontally and I want them vertically.

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout_customers);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView tw_name = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
TextView tw_email = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
TextView tw_phone = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

tw_name.setText("Mr Foo");
tw_email.setText("mrfoo@bar.ninja");
tw_phone.setText("123");

row.addView(tw_name);
row.addView(tw_email);
row.addView(tw_phone);

table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I have tried this:

```
 row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
 row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

.. but this was not it, apparently. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inserting a TableRow, insert another TableLayout and put your item into this second Layout.
You're confused by the fact the name TableRow seems to mean each element inside of it will be put into a new row. But that's not the case. TableRow means "this a new row". So TableRow creates a new line and all item inside of it are... on this new line (so aligned horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

You have only one instance of table row that why its appending all text view in horizontal order. For each row create one table row instance and add text view to each instance it will create one row for each textview.